# What does the "ant or aunt'' means?

Tags: slang

What does the "ant or aunt'' means? (see below: right bottom)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they're playing a game, with each person trying to figure out which word the other is saying.
Ant/Aunt are homophones in many English dialects.